# Simplifying polynomial fraction

Tags: polynomials

Working through an old book I got and am at this problem: Simplify:

$$\frac{3x^2 + 3x -6}{2x^2 + 6x + 4}.$$

The answer is supposed to be $\frac{3(x - 1)}{2(x - 1)}$. I thought I had all this polynomial stuff figured out well enough, but I'm having trouble seeing how they got to that answer. :/

Comment: denominator should be $2(x+1)$, I suppose.

Comment: No, the answer is supposed to be $\frac{3(x-1)}{2(x+1)}$, with a factor of $(x+1)$ on the bottom, not a factor $(x-1)$.

Comment: @DavidH exactly my point! I can't edit the question,however.

Comment: Crap, must have messed up writing the question. Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$3x^2+3x-6 = 3(x^2+x-2)=3(x-1)(x+2)$$

$$2x^2+6x+4 = 2(x^2+3x+2)=2(x+1)(x+2)$$

Comment: Ok, wow, I was really over thinking that one. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

Simply factorise

$\dfrac{3x^2 + 3x -6}{2x^2 + 6x + 4} = \dfrac{3(x^2 + x -2)}{2(x^2 + 3x + 2)} = \dfrac{3(x-1)(x+2)}{2(x+1)(x+2)}$

Then cancel common terms.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{3x^2 + 3x -6}{2x^2 + 6x + 4} = \frac{3(x^2 + x -2)}{2(x^2 + 3x + 2)}= \frac{3\require{cancel}\cancel{(x+2)}(x-1)}{2(x+1)\cancel{(x + 2)}}=\frac{3(x-1)}{2(x+1)}$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

First of all, you could start factoring both numerator and denominator $$\frac{3x^2+3x-6}{2x^2+6x+4}=\frac{3(x^2+x-2)}{2(x^2+3x+2)}$$ In order to factor them, you can then compute the roots of the quadratics : for the numerator, the roots are obviously $1$ and $-2$ and for the denominator $-1$ and $-2$ (you can solve for them or just find by inspection).So, $$\frac{3x^2+3x-6}{2x^2+6x+4}=\frac{3(x^2+x-2)}{2(x^2+3x+2)}=\frac{3(x-1)(x+2)}{2(x+1)(x+2)}$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{3x^2 + 3x -6}{2x^2 + 6x + 4}=\frac{3(x^2 + x -2)}{2(x^2 + 3x + 2)}=$$
$$=\frac{3(x^2 -1+ x -1)}{2(x^2 + 2x+x + 2)}=\frac{3((x-1)(x+1)+(x-1))}{2(x(x+2)+(x+ 2)}=$$
$$=\frac{3(x-1)(x+1+1)}{2(x+2)(x+ 1)}=\frac{3(x-1)(x+2)}{2(x+2)(x+1)}=\frac{3(x-1)}{2(x+1)}$$

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to (the admittedly easy) factoring of the quadratics consists in [taking the gcd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm#Polynomials) of numerator and denominator, and dividing both by it. This may turn useful in more complicated circumstances.